# Class Hoisting in HTML Component

Tags: html, angular, class

I have a class,

```
export class Customer() {
  id: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;

  getFullName() {
    return firstname + ' ' + lastname;
  }
}
```

I have an object in my component.html that i want to give as a parameter to an object
it is supposed to be of class Customer but unfortunatley it treates it as a normal object so it doesn't find this function in customer, this is my Expected Result:

```
<div (click)="myFunc(customer.getFullName())">Click Me!</div>
```

I had to construct the class inside the function

```
myFunc(customer) {
  let fullName = new Customer(customer).getFullName();
  // perform action on fullName
}
```

how do i construct the variable customer to be of class Customer in html instead of doing that in a function.

I want to be able to do something like the code below:

```
<div (click)="myFunc(new Customer(customer).getFullName())">Click Me!</div>
```

is it even possible??

Comment: Where do you get the `customer` object from? Can you turn that into a `Customer` instance before it even hits the HTML part?

Comment: it comes from a Customer[] type, but somehow loses it's class...

Comment: Could you[edit] and  include a little more context please?